# Send sms using kannel & smmpsim

Tags: docker, kannel

I'm trying to send sms using kannel & smppsim.
I use docker as container.
I use this kannel.conf:

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = bar
admin-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1;192.168.59.103"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1;192.168.59.103"

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = SMPPSim
host = 192.168.59.103
port = 2775
transceiver-mode = 1
smsc-username = smppclient1
smsc-password = password
system-type = 'VMA'
#service-type = 'test'
interface-version = 34
#system-id = smppclient
preferred-smsc-id = SMPPSim
connect-allow-ip = 192.168.59.103

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = bearerbox
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = 13013

group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar

group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"
```

when sending a request to send sms I get "0: Accepted for delivery"

I'm seeing these errors in smsbox log:

```
2015-03-21 20:20:52 [1] [3] DEBUG: Status: 202 Answer: <Sent.>
2015-03-21 20:20:52 [1] [3] DEBUG: Delayed reply - wait for bearerbox
2015-03-21 20:20:52 [1] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of 74f9cefe-db95-4b7d-aa99-f07395d32915
2015-03-21 20:20:52 [1] [0] DEBUG: HTTP: Resetting HTTPClient for `192.168.59.3'.
2015-03-21 20:20:52 [1] [1] ERROR: Error reading from fd 24:
2015-03-21 20:20:52 [1] [1] ERROR: System error 104: Connection reset by peer
2015-03-21 20:20:52 [1] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7fe8d0000ad0.
```

Bearbox doesn't present any errors and seem to pass the message to smppsim, smppsim shows this in log:

```
21 Assessing state of 1 messages in the OutboundQueue
21 Message:2 state=DELIVERED
```

The sms is not sent, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a problem with your Kannel configuration file, specially with smsbox and later parts. I used following as smsbox

```
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = your sim number which you use in USB modem
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/var/log/kannel/access.log"
```

and you can get my full configuration file from [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VtH8OLg9fVB7qln5oW2oRaEJ73Sfb7-94M_Ngs4UfEo/edit?usp=sharing). This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem of lоѕѕ оf thе соnnесtіоn оn thе rеmоtе ѕосkеt due tо а tіmеоut. 
And SMPPSim is just a testing tool for kannel. It won't really send a message to your or mentioned mobile number. To send real messages you need to add either gsm modems or SMS operator details.
You can refer to userGuide from kannel.org.
To check your kannel status simply go to http://localhost:13000/status?password=password(password of your kannel)